# Confusion on DB2 Connection

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

The question that I will ask does not contain any exception or anything. That's where the confusion coming from.
I have been migrating one old legacy application -which connects and writes to Database- to java8. It used to use the db2 library along with the license from `/home/db2client/v95fp2/sqllib/java/db2jcc_license_cu.jar:/home/db2client/v95fp2/sqllib/java/db2jcc.jar`. And when I check the details of the `db2jcc.jar` it says `IBM DB2 JDBC Universal Driver Architecture`.

Now, deleted that library from the classpath and added my new jar under the lib directory of the project  `db2jcc4-10.5fp11-fp11.jar` and deleted the `db2jcc_license_cu.jar` And when I check the details of the new jar it says `IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ`. (The reason I changed to the new jar was there was some java8 combability problems in between the old one and java8)

Eventhough I do not have the license and the jars are different, my application still manages to run and write to the database without an exception. This is the reason I am very confused at the moment.

What is the difference between Universal Driver Architecture one and the Data Server Driver for JDBC SQLJ? And why is it still able to run? I have been reading the whole IBM manuals but I still do not know.

I am aware it may not be a type of question that is asked here, but I think that'd help me a lot to understand what's happening.